# How to configure certain RPM in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm using the *Constant Throughput Timer* and I expect some specific rpm (e.g. 100). Also I have a *JSR223 sampler* in my scenario which generates the data for the request.

When I run the script I see the throughput in *Summary report*, smth like:

```
jsr223   56  rpm
request  44  rpm
TOTAL    100 rpm
```

Each time rpm correlation between jsr223 and request is different, but total is about 100 *(it's clear for me)*.

How should I configure the scenario to have 100 rpm for request only?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Constant Throughput Timer` under the `request`

```
jsr223
request
   Constant Throughput Timer - 100 rpm
```

This will ensure that request is made minimum 100 per minute.

Remember - if the application itself is not supporting the desired throughput, jmeter can not help here.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't come to my mind that CTT could be placed under the request))